# Gmaps4rails: How to create rich marker in javascript?

Tags: javascript, gmaps4rails

I add a marker to user location like this:

```
Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
  Gmaps.map.createMarker({Lat: lat,
                          Lng: lng, 
                          rich_marker: null, 
                          marker_picture: ""
  });
}
```

, but I'd like to change the image of the marker. Rich marker seems to be the solution, but I can't get the rich_marker constructed correctly.

Could anyone give an example of rich marker construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
  Gmaps.map.rich_marker = true;
  Gmaps.map.createMarker({Lat: lat,
                      Lng: lng, 
                      rich_marker: your_custom_html, 
                      marker_picture: ""
  });
}
```

Comment: I can't understand why, after all these years being the leading gmaps gem, it's so unclear in the documentation how to do stuff like these.

Comment: For example, where do we add this code? which time we render it? does it works with turbolinks? should it be inside the partial or inside the main javascript file... it runs inside the handler setup or after? simple questions that we cannot get a clue in the doc.

Comment: man... im sorry (an  very grateful for you to do this gem) but I know very well this doc and your gem... The direction that you took is perfect, but the execution is too complicated...